# Very bad Zero Shot classification predictions from ZeroShot Models on Hugging face

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, transformer-model, huggingface

I am currently trying to use two Hugging Face zero shot model for classification. Unfortunately, the results are extremely poor (almost random). Likewise, I get different results when I use the template for the example on the hugging face webpage page, then running it via own code and pipeline. Therefore, I think I am doing something wrong with my code. Additionally, I also get some warnings. Maybe you can help me out

My Code for the first Model:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-xnli")
sequence_to_classify = "This is a very cool Video"
candidate_labels = ["Praise", "Criticism", "Question"]
output = classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels, multi_label=False)
print(output)
```

Output inkl. warnings:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\anaconda3\envs\zero-shot-env\lib\site-packages\transformers\convert_slow_tokenizer.py:454: UserWarning: The sentencepiece tokenizer that you are converting to a fast tokenizer uses the byte fallback option which is not implemented in the fast tokenizers. In practice this means that the fast version of the tokenizer can produce unknown tokens whereas the sentencepiece version would have converted these unknown tokens into a sequence of byte tokens matching the original piece of text.
  warnings.warn(
{'sequence': 'This is a very cool Video', 'labels': ['Praise', 'Criticism', 'Question'], 'scores': [0.6537378430366516, 0.28773054480552673, 0.05853160098195076]}
```

If I use the same input on the [Hugging face Webpage](https://huggingface.co/MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-xnli-multilingual-nli-2mil7?candidateLabels=Praise%2C%20Criticism%2C%20Question&multiClass=false&text=This%20is%20a%20very%20cool%20Video) the result is:

```
Praise  0.789
Criticism  0.157
Question  0.053
```

In this case, it is close together, but in other cases the values between the Hugging Face Page and the code/pipeline are completly different.

I installed `sentencepiece`, but the warning still appears.

For the second model I use it is the same problem but with a different Warning:

The Code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification",
                      model="joeddav/xlm-roberta-large-xnli")
sequence_to_classify = "This is a very cool Video"
candidate_labels = ["Praise", "Criticism", "Question"]
output = classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels, multi_label=False)
print(output)
```

The Output:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at joeddav/xlm-roberta-large-xnli were not used when initializing XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification: ['roberta.pooler.dense.bias', 'roberta.pooler.dense.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
{'sequence': 'This is a very cool Video', 'labels': ['Praise', 'Criticism', 'Question'], 'scores': [0.6573342680931091, 0.24442064762115479, 0.09824512898921967]}
```

The Values are also different to the Hugging face webpage. I also do not get what the warning means. Because I use this model in a zero shot setting and did not change the architecture or something. Maybe you know more, very happy for help!

PS: Here is my conda env list

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda-client           1.11.2          py310haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.4.1           py310haa95532_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py310haa95532_0
attrs                     22.1.0          py310haa95532_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2          py310haa95532_0
boltons                   23.0.0          py310haa95532_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h2bbff1b_1002
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.05.30           haa95532_0
certifi                   2023.7.22       py310haa95532_0
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h2bbff1b_3
chardet                   4.0.0           py310haa95532_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.4           py310haa95532_0
clyent                    1.2.2           py310haa95532_1
colorama                  0.4.6           py310haa95532_0
conda                     23.7.3          py310haa95532_0
conda-build               3.24.0          py310haa95532_0
conda-content-trust       0.1.3           py310haa95532_0
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    2.0.2           py310haa95532_0
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0           py310haa95532_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.41          py310haa95532_0
conda-token               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cryptography              39.0.1          py310h21b164f_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
filelock                  3.9.0           py310haa95532_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
future                    0.18.3          py310haa95532_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_2
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.4             py310haa95532_0
jinja2                    3.1.2           py310haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonpatch                 1.32               pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonpointer               2.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.17.3          py310haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.3.0           py310haa95532_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h5b6d351_1
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libarchive                3.6.2                h2033e3e_1
libclang                  14.0.6          default_hb5a9fac_1
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h8e68704_1
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_0
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
liblief                   0.12.3               hd77b12b_0
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libpq                     12.15                h906ac69_0
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6c2663c_2
libwebp                   1.2.4                hbc33d0d_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h2bbff1b_1
libxml2                   2.10.4               h0ad7f3c_1
libxslt                   1.1.37               h2bbff1b_1
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_0
m2-msys2-runtime          2.5.0.17080.65c939c               3
m2-patch                  2.7.5                         2
markupsafe                2.1.1           py310h2bbff1b_0
menuinst                  1.4.19          py310h59b6b97_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
navigator-updater         0.4.0           py310haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.7.0           py310haa95532_0
openssl                   1.1.1v               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 23.0            py310haa95532_0
pathlib                   1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pillow                    9.4.0           py310hd77b12b_0
pip                       22.3.1          py310haa95532_0
pkginfo                   1.9.6           py310haa95532_0
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310haa95532_0
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310haa95532_1
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
py-lief                   0.12.3          py310hd77b12b_0
pycosat                   0.6.4           py310h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.4.0           py310haa95532_0
pyopenssl                 23.2.0          py310haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.7          py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0         py310hd77b12b_0
pyrsistent                0.18.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
python                    3.10.9               h966fe2a_1
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310haa95532_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
pytz                      2022.7          py310haa95532_0
pywin32                   305             py310h2bbff1b_0
pyyaml                    6.0             py310h2bbff1b_1
qt-main                   5.15.2               h6072711_9
qt-webengine              5.15.9               h5bd16bc_7
qtpy                      2.2.0           py310haa95532_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h2bbfb41_5
requests                  2.31.0          py310haa95532_0
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0           py310haa95532_0
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py310h2bbff1b_0
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6           py310h2bbff1b_1
ruamel_yaml               0.17.21         py310h2bbff1b_0
setuptools                65.6.3          py310haa95532_0
sip                       6.6.2           py310hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
soupsieve                 2.4             py310haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1           py310haa95532_0
toolz                     0.12.0          py310haa95532_0
tornado                   6.3.2           py310h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.65.0          py310h9909e9c_0
traitlets                 5.7.1           py310haa95532_0
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0
ujson                     5.4.0           py310hd77b12b_0
urllib3                   1.26.16         py310haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.38.4          py310haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2             py310haa95532_2
xz                        5.4.2                h8cc25b3_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```